# How to Query nested object in Firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase in android.

I am having trouble in querying the below json.

I am having is an array of objects. A single object is posted below:

```
{
      "currency" : "₹",
      "groups" : {
        "-L9Q5d3T_XBBQGJygGqJ" : {
          "group_id" : "-L9Q5d3T_XBBQGJygGqJ",
          "group_name" : "Group 1"
        }
      },
      "groups_uid" : "-L9Q5d3T_XBBQGJygGqJ",
      "name" : "Sample 1 ",
      "number" : "1234567890",
    }
```

`orderByChild("groups_uid").equalTo("-L9Q5d3T_XBBQGJygGqJ")` works

But how to query `orderByChild("groups").equalTo("-L9Q5d3T_XBBQGJygGqJ")` doesn't work.

Now I wanted to query like: Get all the objects having groups/{some id}/group_id = some value.

**I need the objects the one I posted from array which matches groups/{some_id}**

Can anyone help me with this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like :

```
Query query = firebaseServices.getUserData();

query.orderByChild("groups/-L9Q5d3T_XBBQGJygGqJ/group_id").equalTo(groupWiseModel.getId())
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks alot